# Questions about the using of pooled variance method by determining the parameter "b" in order to get a mathematical and mostly physical good result

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I take over the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908151/how-to-derive-pooled-sample-variance) since I have not all understood the calculation done :

> Let $s_p^2 = bs_1^2 + (1-b)s_2^2$, this can be an unbiased estimator
> of population variance, provided we find the correct value for $b$; in
> particular, $s_p^2 = \frac{(n1-1)s_1^2 + (n_2-1)s_2^2}{n_1+n_2-2}$ is
> an unbiased estimator
>
> To minimize variance of $s_p^2 = bs_1^2 + (1-b)s_2^2:V(s_p^2)=b^2
> > V(s_1^2) + (1-b)^2 V(s_2^2)$ we need to find $\frac{d}{db}V(s_p^2)=0$
> but I cannot solve this for $s_p^2$.

and the answer :

> Lets start with $s_p^2 = bs_1^2 + (1-b)s_2^2:V(s_p^2)=b^2 V(s_1^2) +
> > (1-b)^2 V(s_2^2)$
>
> $\frac{d}{db} V(s_p^2)=2bV(s_1^2)-2(1-b)V(s_2^2)=0 \implies
> > \frac{b}{1-b} = \frac{Var(s_2^2)}{Var(s_1^2)}$
>
> As you can see, $b,(1-b)$ is inversely proportional to the variance of
> $s_1^2,s_2^2$ respectively.
>
> Now, if they both come from the same population (with assumed same
> variance), this implies that $Var(s_1^2)=\frac{n_2}{n_1} Var(s_2^2)
> > \rightarrow \frac{b}{1-b} =
> > \frac{Var(s_2^2)}{Var(s_1^2)}=\frac{n_1}{n_2} \implies
> > n_2b-n_1(1-b)=b(n_2+n_1)-n_1=0 \rightarrow b=\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}$
>
> This means that the larger the sample size for sample 1 relative to
> sample 2, the more weight we give to sample 1.

1. How can I prove that $s_p^2 = b\,s_1^2 + (1-b)\,s_2^2$ can be an unbiased estimator of population variance with appropriate $b$ factor ?
2. Could anyone tell me please the difference between the maximum likelihood estimator initialy used in the original answer and the fix to replace $n$ by $n-1$ (located in comments) ?

Indeed, I am looking for using pooled variance method by determining the parameter "$b$" that I would like to fix in order to get a mathematical and mostly physical better results.

Sorry, it is not really a duplicate, rather a problem of understand well what is done.

Comment: You need to equate $bs_1^2 + (1-b)s_2^2$ and $s_p^2 = \frac{(n1-1)s_1^2 + (n_2-1)s_2^2}{n_1+n_2-2}.$ What does $b$ have be be? Before you do algebra, just _look at it._

Comment: @BruceET . Thanks for your quick answer. Indeed, logical. But just a last detail, how to justify that if we consider the same population, then we have $$\frac{Var(s_2^2)}{Var(s_1^2)}=\frac{n_1-1}{n_2-1}$$ ? Regards